# How do I create a messaging system in MVC 5 using Ninject 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I achieve a global messaging system in MVC 5 with Ninject 3? 
 What I'm trying to achieve is simple:

I'd like to add a message, like: "You successfully completed the task" and read it into the _Layout view. I would use ViewBag, ViewData or TempData for this. The problem is that for separating concerns I have done much of the processing logic outside the controller scope (through dependency injection). Meaning that ViewBag, ViewData and TempData aren't possible (unless I extend the injected class with the Controller)

So what I tried was creating a global static class that handled the task. The problem is that the class is shown to ALL users of the application independently of their authentication.

Comment: Have you looked at `SignalR`

Answer (score 2):

Most of the credit goes to levelnis from asp.net forums and his post [Send Success Message to View using TempData](http://levelnis.co.uk/blog/send-success-message-to-view-using-tempdata)

You can check his post in the link above. The code is mainly the same, I just trimmed down some functionality that I did not need and at the end, I use Ninject instead of Autofac (which was the IoC container levelnis used)

**Objective:**
You want to achieve a global Messaging System using ASP.NET MVC 5 when using Ninject 3 as IoC container.

*Before starting I'll assume the following:*

1. You have ASP.NET MVC 3 or higher installed
2. You are using Ninject 3
3. You have already configured Ninject and have a little knowledge about it.
4. I have assummed you know basic separation of concerns, and divide the classes and files according to a good judgement.
5. Although not mandatory, I'm using Bootstrap in this case for HTML formatting.

**Solution:**

1st. Create a new file on your solution and name it "MessageSystem.cs" This is the class file that will hold our Messages.

2nd. Fill it with the following code:

```
public class MessageSystem
{
     //This is for bootstrap. This will reference what type of alert we will throw.
    public MessageType Type { get; set; }
    //Where the message you want to say will be held
    public string Message { get; set; }

    //Creates the HTML string.
    //This outputs the div in HTML with the current message formatted. 
    public string Generate()
    {
        //Div Tag
        var divTag = new TagBuilder("div");
            divTag.AddCssClass("alert alert-" + Type.ToString());
            divTag.InnerHtml = Message + "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove js-close\"></span>";

            return divTag.ToString();

    }
}
 //The bootstrap alert types.
public enum MessageType
{
    success,
    info,
    warning,
    danger
}
```

The class above takes care of generating the HTML needed for displaying the message. Note that this has been done like this to prevent the least tampering within the view.

3rd. We will create a Notifier class which will be the one responsible for storing the messages and adding them. We also take the chance and create its interface.This will be the one who will be injected later on.

```
public interface INotifier
{
    IList<MessageSystem> Messages { get; }
    void AddMessage(MessageType type, string Message);

}

/**
 * public class Notifier : INotifier
 * 
 * Purpose: Main class which will take care of adding the messages for us.
 * 
 * */

public class Notifier : INotifier
{
    //List of messages so we can display multiple for the user.
    public IList<MessageSystem> Messages { get; private set; }

    public Notifier()
    {
        Messages = new List<MessageSystem>();
    }

    //Adds the message to the current Messages variable. 
    public void AddMessage(MessageType type, string Message)
    {
        Messages.Add(new MessageSystem
        {
            Type = type,
            Message = Message
        });
    }

}
```

The Notifier class has a public IList item which is in charge of holding all of our messages, in case we would like to display more than one message to the user!

The constructor: Notifier() takes care of giving the IList an instance of List() so we can add later on our messages.

```
//Just for convenience and a placeholder
//Since I will need to use the TempDataKey 
//multiple times, it's more convenient to put it as a const. 
public static class ConstKeys
{
    public const string TempDataKey = "Messages";
}

/**
 * public static class NotifierExtensions
 * 
 * Purpsoe: This isn't extremely necessary, it's just a helper that will simplify things
 *          quite a bit. This will allow you to create a layer of decoupleness which you 
 *          can change later on. 
 *          
 *          In other words, this will allow you to add the message with the MessageType according
 *          to the scenario. 
 * 
 * */
public static class NotifierExtensions
{
    public static void Error(this INotifier notifier, string text)
    {
        notifier.AddMessage(MessageType.danger, text);
    }

    public static void Info(this INotifier notifier, string text)
    {
        notifier.AddMessage(MessageType.info, text);
    }

    public static void Success(this INotifier notifier, string text)
    {
        notifier.AddMessage(MessageType.success, text);
    }

    public static void Warning(this INotifier notifier, string text)
    {
        notifier.AddMessage(MessageType.warning, text);
    }

    //This is the method that takes care of using it directly on your view
    //You'll use it like @Html.ViewContext.DisplayMessages()
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayMessages(this ViewContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Controller.TempData.ContainsKey(ConstKeys.TempDataKey))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var messages = (IEnumerable<MessageSystem>)context.Controller.TempData[ConstKeys.TempDataKey];
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            builder.AppendLine(message.Generate());
        }

        return builder.ToHtmlString();
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString ToHtmlString(this StringBuilder input)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(input.ToString());
    }
}
```

4th. Implement the ActionFilter, which will be the one responsible to grab the global TempData which will hold your messages:

```
/**
 *  public class NotifierFilterAttribute : IActionFilter
 * */

public class NotifierFilterAttribute : IActionFilter
{
    private INotifier Notifier;

    /**
     * This is the tricky part. We can't do constructor injections automatically on Action Filters. 
     * Microsoft has taken notice and fixed this issue in MVC 6. What we are going to do 
     * in here is that we will use Ninject to inject this whole class to the filter pipeline instead
     * of using the built-in way of MVC 5. With that possibility Ninject will be able to inject the 
     * INotifier object successfully. 
     * */
    public NotifierFilterAttribute(INotifier Notifier)
    {
        this.Notifier = Notifier;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        var messages = Notifier.Messages;

        if(messages.Any())
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData[ConstKeys.TempDataKey] = messages;
        }

    }

    //We will not be using this. But since this is an interface we need to implement it.
    //We will leave it blank since we will not be using it. 
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) { }

}
```

As specified in the comments above, Action Filters called via MVC do not support constructor injection automatically.

*Worry not, we're almost finished!*

In your solution, you must have defined a RegisterService() method for Ninject, it should look like this:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
```

5th. **Inside that method** add the following:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        //Your original code unmodified. Omitted for convenience 

        //This is the messaging system.
        kernel.BindFilter<NotifierFilterAttribute>(FilterScope.Controller, 0);
    }
```

In the previous chunk of code above, we have told Ninject to inject the NotifierFilterAttribute **EVERYWHERE**. In case you wanted to add your class on specific controllers, you must add the .When clause after the (FIlterScope.Controller,0). This gets out of the scope of this tutorial, so I won't be including it here.

Notice that, for BindFilter to work you must have the following reference to the file:

```
using Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax;
```

*In my case, Visual Studio didn't resolve the dependency automatically. That's why I'm showing it here.*

6th. Look on your solution where you are putting your Ninject's bindings.

They are usually under the following method:

```
private void AddBindings()
```

Inside it, **add** the following line of code:

```
kernel.Bind<INotifier>().To<Notifier>().InRequestScope();
```

*As it happened above, include the following using for InRequestScope to work, because VS did not recognize it.*

```
using Ninject.Web.Common;
```

Ninject will automagically create the Notifier object and insert it wherever INotifier is called.  We add InRequestScope() because we need to have the SAME object instantiated throughout the whole app. Otherwise it will not work, and you would receive an empty Notifier object on the Action Filter.

7th. Use it anywhere!

```
 public class ArticleController : Controller
{
    readonly INotifier notifier;

    public ArticleController(INotifier notifier)
    {
       this.notifier = notifier;
    }


    // GET: Content
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        notifier.Success("Yahoo!");
        return View();

    }
```

}

8th Last part: Put where your messages are going to be read. If you want them to appear on every page, put the following line on your _Layout.cshtml file:

```
@Html.ViewContext.DisplayMessages()
```

*The HTML outputted comes from the Generate() method from the MessageSystem class, in case you need some modification.*

That's it!

I'm very sorry for being so verbose. I just wanted to be as clear as possible.

Where original question originated:

http://forums.asp.net/p/2062006/5957330.aspx?p=True&t=635762674289334403